# Open Badges/Tin Can to open up credential & learning data

Tags: uses-of-open-data

What are the differences between http://tincanapi.com/  & http://openbadges.org/ ?

I think they are both great ways in opening up credential data, but was wondering in what specific situations you would use one or the other?
Both as provider of open badges/tin can api as on the receiver side of these (learner)

Comment: I think this question is likely toeing the line on being considered about 'open data'.  Yes, there are two APIs with a similar intent that are both around communities that are collecting data about people ... but this seems like it'd be more appropriate to ask on webmasters.SE .  I don't want to be heavy handed and just close or move it, but if other people vote to do so, I'll act on it.

Comment: @Joe , I can agree with that... I should maybe rephrase my question because it is also from an 'open data' point of view, that I would like to know what the differences are. For me they are both about opening data that is hard to open because of privacy issues, both are trying to solve this with giving the data in hands of the owner of the data but I am not sure in which they differ concerning that

Comment: I don't think it's difficult from a privacy point of view, because the person has to actively engage with specific systems for their data to be collected.  Most privacy concerns are when companies collect data without the person being aware that it's being collected, and then using it in ways that the user isn't aware of.  There's maybe a chance for the second one, but very few would be abusive (maybe selling your info to head hunters who would them harrass you), but the first one would be more difficult ... it'd be like complaining that facebook knew who your friends are.

Comment: it's more like facebook obliging you to let others know who your friends are...let me explain by the case of CV fraud.... nowadays anyone can say whatever he wants about himself on his linkedin profile. Nobody can check or authenticate if you really have those 5 postdoc degrees.. (without trying to get that authenticated via the issuer of the degrees).... with an api like tin can or open badges, that check can be immediately made..it takes away the possibility for a person to cheat on this...is that privacy?, maybe me not, but it sure can devaluate data that doesn't have that authentication

Comment: i see open badges (micro-credentials) as being a key ingredient into verification in a decentralized ecosystem. and open badges are powered by open data.

Answer (score 1):

The differences between Tin Can and Open Badges seem to be that Tin Can is for one particular sector of micro-credentials (experiences) whereas Open Badges covers all sectors of micro-credentials.